# Override or disable DEFAULT_PASSWORD_ENROLL_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_DAYS?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

We are sending out account invitation messages to users, using `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail`. In some cases, users fail to click the link for some time. In those cases, we have to re-send the invitations, making extra work for admin users.

The Meteor Accounts package seems to use `DEFAULT_PASSWORD_ENROLL_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_DAYS` to expire activation links. Is it possible to override this value or disable it?

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: We fixed the issue with:
```
Accounts.config({
  passwordEnrollTokenExpirationInDays: 60
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to fix the issue with the following, e.g. in `accounts.js`:

```js
Accounts.config({
  passwordEnrollTokenExpirationInDays: 60
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As I found in the [code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/af26e8b052a5135033e561cf4e4347eee585ab3b/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L312) it is a const with a fixed value.

You therefore won't be able to override it by default.

However you still have some options here.

1. Override the `accounts-base` package and use values from `process.env` or `Meteor.settings` for the expiration variable.
2. Use [additional token data](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendEnrollmentEmail) in `sendEnrollmentEmail` and place a custom expiration date there. Then use [`onEnrollmentLink`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-onEnrollmentLink) to make a custom validation of the expiration date.
3. Use a custom Collection to store expiration dates and check them in [onEnrollmentLink](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-onEnrollmentLink)

If you prefer the first option it would be great if you also open a PR on the Meteor repo so others will benefit from it.